# Data Migration Question

Tags: data-import

I am a new Salesforce user and longtime software developer. I'm in the process of migrating a custom application from a .NET solution to Salesforce. Now that it's pretty much ready, I need to migrate all the existing Users and associated objects. I'm starting with Users as that seems to be the base object, but I don't understand the `ProfileID` requirement. How do I import new users, who aren't in Salesforce and don't have a `ProfileId` when I need to have a `profileID`? Is there another object that needs to be imported or created first?

I'm using Data Loader 42.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Profiles are part of the configuration of your organization. You'll want to create those prior to performing a user import, as the profile defines the data and system functionality rights of the user.

That said, if you are bringing your users in in an inactive state, there's no reason you cannot create a single placeholder profile, populate its Id in your import files as the `ProfileId` for all users, and later perform a data update pass to substitute the Ids of the "real" profiles that you intend to use in production, before you activate the users and provide them with access to the system.